# Cannot assign "(<User: jack>, True)" "Profile.user" must be a "User" instance

Tags: django

i Use One-To-One Link With a User Model (Profile)
and i got this error when i try to make user registration 
Cannot assign "(, True)": "Profile.user" must be a "User" instance.
and this is user_registration uses in my project 
thanks for help

```
def user_registration(request):
    form = UserRegistrationForm()
      if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            structure= form.cleaned_data['structure'].id
            user = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username,  password=password)
            profile=Profile.objects.create(structure_id=structure,user=user)
            profile.save()
            messages.success(request,
            'Enregistrement avec succés {}'.format(user.username))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('compte:login'))   
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
        return render(request,'compte/register.html',{'form':form})
```

this is my traceback :

[01/Aug/2019 22:01:13] "GET /compte/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2194
[01/Aug/2019 22:01:16] "GET /static/js/popper.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1773
[01/Aug/2019 22:01:16] "GET /static/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1806
[01/Aug/2019 22:01:16] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1782
[01/Aug/2019 22:01:16] "GET /compte/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2194
[01/Aug/2019 22:01:16] "GET /static/js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1806
[01/Aug/2019 22:01:16] "GET /static/js/popper.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1773
[01/Aug/2019 22:01:16] "GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1782
Internal Server Error: /compte/register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/investissement/Invest_App/compte/views.py", line 38, in user_registration
    profile=Profile.objects.create(structure_id=structure,user=user)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 420, in create
    obj = self.model(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 483, in **init**
    _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 301, in **set**
    super().**set**(instance, value)
  File   "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-  packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 211, in    **set**
     self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
     ValueError: Cannot assign "(, True)": "Profile.user"   must be a "User" instance.
    [01/Aug/2019 22:01:25] "POST /compte/register/ HTTP/1.1" 500 91942

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [**`.get_or_create(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) will return a 2-tuple with the first item the object generated, and the second a `bool`ean that specifies if it created a new object. You thus can use iterable unpacking here, to get access to the first element.

```
def user_registration(request):
    form = UserRegistrationForm()
      if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            structure = form.cleaned_data['structure'].id
            user, __ = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username,  password=password)
            profile = Profile.objects.create(structure_id=structure,user=user)
            profile.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Enregistrement avec succés {}'.format(user.username))
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('compte:login'))   
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
        return render(request,'compte/register.html',{'form':form})
```

That being said, the above will not work, since passwords are *not* saved as raw text in the database, but hashed. You this will need to set the password with [**`.set_password(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.set_password). You might want to use [**`.update_or_create(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) for your `Profile`, to prevent errors in case the profile already exists for that user:

```
def user_registration(request):
    form = UserRegistrationForm()
      if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            structure = form.cleaned_data['structure'].id
            user, __ = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            Profile.objects.update_or_create(
                user=user,
                defaults={'structure_id': structure}
            )
            messages.success(request, 'Enregistrement avec succés {}'.format(user.username))
        return redirect('compte:login')
    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
        return render(request,'compte/register.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: thank you i understand i will try it and i tell you the result thanks

Comment: i try it and i got this error : duplicate key value violates unique constraint "compte_profile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(13) already exists.

Comment: @azizianoir: that error means you already created a `Profile` for that user. Perhaps you should use a `get_or_create` for `Profile` as well?

Comment: i edit the view by add get_or_create and i  got same error :duplicate key value violates unique constraint "compte_profile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(14) already exists.

Comment: @azizianoir: it is `update_or_create`, not `get_or_create`.

Comment: I'm quite sure that the error is not in the `user_registration` then? Perhaps a signal or something else. Can you edit the question with the *full* traceback?

Comment: i try update_or_create and i got same error ..duplicate key value violates unique constraint "compte_profile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(16) already exists.

Comment: @azizianoir: can you please share the *full* traceback in your question?

Comment: what u mean by full traceback ??

Comment: @azizianoir: see https://realpython.com/python-traceback/ it is the entire trace of the exception.

Comment: raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "compte_profile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(16) already exists.

Comment: @azizianoir: please edit your question, and with the *full* traceback. Not the last lines...

Comment: id put my traceback

Comment: @azizianoir: but the traceback clearly indicates that you still use `profile=Profile.objects.create(structure_id=structure,user=user)`, instead of `Profile.objects.update_or_create(..)` (in the last code fragment)

Comment: i do this changes and i get this error now int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'User'

Answer (score 1):

`get_or_create` returns a tuple of the item and a boolean indicating whether it was created. You should capture both:

```
user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=username,  password=password)
profile = Profile.objects.create(structure_id=structure,user=user)
```

However, you shouldn't do this either. By doing this you're ensuring that the password is saved without hashing; and in any case, `username` is a unique field, so the form will not be valid if the username already exists.

Call form.save directly:

```
user = form.save()
```

Note also, you don't need to call `profile.save()`, as `create` saves the item itself.

Comment: Hi Daniel, just a follow-up question. Would this be fixed by saving the user too? e.g `user = user.save()`?

Comment: @Paolo: don't set `user = user.save()`, just `user.save()`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Awesome! I was quite confused if you should be setting the user. Thanks for the clarification!